# CodeIgniter Marking checkboxes from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I want to repopulate a page that contains checkboxes from values in the database. Currently, they are being stored as a string that gets split into an array when processing e.g 3,4,5.

I am able to check the boxes with the data from my database but another empty checkbox is created by its side. How do I only check the boxes with data from the database without having a duplicate empty box by its side?

```
<tbody>               
       <?php 
           if(!empty($datatable)){
              foreach ($datatable as $data){
        ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php foreach ($event_contacts as $checked){?>
                                <?php if($checked==$data->id){?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id" checked value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>"/>
                            <?php }else{ ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id" value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>"/>
                            <?php }}?>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->first_name." ".$data->last_name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->phone_number; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $data->address;?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks

EDIT: Added photo for clarity

[image]

Comment: how do you knew that it was duplicated? lets assume that you have 5 rows in your table, and only two of them have the checked label, you foreach loop will continue in creating your check-boxes, until you remove your else statement

Comment: If I remove the else then only the checked boxes will appear though.

Comment: so how do you knew that it's duplicated? check out your element inspector and see

Comment: Sorry, its not duplicated. Its the unchecked version that is created.

Comment: Huh? But I haven't solved the issue? If I remove the else, The items that are unchecked won't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your code like this

```
 <tbody>               
   <?php 
       if(!empty($datatable)){
          foreach ($datatable as $data){
    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <?php

                        if (in_array($data->id, $event_contacts)) {
                            ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id" checked value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>"/>
                            <?php
                        }else{

                          ?>
                                   <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id" value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>"/>

                          <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $data->first_name." ".$data->last_name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data->email; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data->phone_number; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data->address;?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php 
                }
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
```